# Realsense plugin how to remove camera display screen from gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: screenshot of gazebo realsense camera]
(link to the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/V6LG64o) )
There is no need for the camera display screen in gazebo as I am using Rviz, and it might be slowing down the simulation. How can we remove it?

System

- ros melodic
- gazebo version 9
- rviz version 1.13.4

Edit:
Realsense plugin that I am using: https://github.com/SyrianSpock/realsense_gazebo_plugin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344975/realsense-plugin-how-to-remove-camera-display-screen-from-gazebo/) by [shanda4](https://answers.ros.org/users/52054/shanda4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @shanda4,

Try to be more specific with the packages and external ROS tools you are using for the next time please.

I assume you are using this [package](https://github.com/intel/gazebo-realsense).

Take a look at this [line](https://github.com/intel/gazebo-realsense/blob/f007e92144a5b20711e7ff5041bab8b2e294ac7f/models/realsense_camera/model.sdf#L106), with it you will be able to disable visibility on Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shanda4](https://answers.ros.org/users/52054/shanda4/) on 2020-02-26**:
Hi @Weasfas, Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question.

In my case, [this line](https://github.com/SyrianSpock/realsense_gazebo_plugin/blob/master/models/realsense_camera/model.sdf#L152) is similar to what you have shared. I will test it in a few hours and accept the answer. Thanks again :).